LVM two paths /var/{lib,log}/foo share one logical volume
I have this application foo which uses two paths on the system which could generate disk full:
/var/lib/foo
/var/log/foo

I want these two paths to use one logical LVM so when the app fills up the disk I only have to increase one logical volume.
It can be done with bind in /etc/fstab but I don't like that idea.
It can also be done with sym-links but that is also kind of messy:
/app/foo # LVM mount point for foo
/var/lib/foo -> /app/foo/lib
/var/log/foo -> /app/foo/log

Is there a better layout than sym-links?
It is possible to configure foo to use other paths for lib and log but I prefer the default configuration (OCD).
Imagine there is more apps on the server like /var/{lib,log}/bar and if that fills up the disk, it only has impact on app bar.

What's wrong with symlinks? That's the kind of thing they're designed for.

Another things you can do is switch from LVM to ZFS where you can have several datasets (organised in a tree structure) that share the same storage pool but can be given different settings including space reservation, compressions, duplication... and can also be snapshotted individually and mounted in arbitrary places.

More generally, to "contain" resource usage of an application, you can use one of many containerisation solutions, but ultimately, when it comes to storage, it will boil down to the same as your bind mounting.

I must admit @Stéphane Chazelas comment is the right thing: Use symlinks
I thought there had come a new best practice with LVM over the years which could make a more simple/clean setup than symlinks.
By using symlinks the setup is so simple that any Linux administrator which should troubleshoot it, quickly will get an overview of the situation without reading a long documentation.
quota makes system a bit slower and it is also filesystem dependable.


I want these two paths to use one logical LVM so when the app fills up the disk I only have to increase one logical volume.

For this to work, the two paths also must share the filesystem. You cannot put two file­systems on a single block device, as they all expect a fixed-size allocation and do not have the possibility to automatically grow or shrink in cooperation with the other filesystems on the same device; so the only option is a single filesystem responsible for the metadata and allocation of the entire device.
Given that, a bind mount that attaches subdirectories of the same filesystem to both locations is exactly how you would achieve this normally. Bind mounts aren't "proxy" mounts; they cause the kernel to directly attach the same mounted filesystem to additional paths; i.e. a single mount (superblock) becomes known by multiple names (somewhat more like hardlinks than symlinks, even if that's not a good analogy) so overall it is exactly what you're asking for.
The other option would be to use a filesystem that has built-in support for datasets or subvolumes, such as ZFS or Btrfs. (With Btrfs, subvolumes behave like directories initially, but can be directly mounted from fstab as well.) Both of those also have their own volume management so that LVM becomes completely redundant.

If all the files generated by the application in both paths are owned by the same user or group, you can use quotas to limit disk usage across both paths, without having to use a different volume.
Enabling quotas varies depending on the file system being used. Typically it will involve either a file system option (for example the quota file system feature in Ext4) and/or mount options. See your file system’s man page for details.
Once quotas are enabled, you can configure them using edquota (part of the quota tools, usually in a quota package) and view them using quota. In some cases you should use a file system-specific tool instead, for example xfs_quota on XFS.
